# On level up, can a UA Mystic swap out their Bonus Disciplines for disciplines that aren't from their Order?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, mystic

[The most recent version (v3) of the Mystic class from Unearthed Arcana can be found here.](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)

All the Mystic Orders (subclasses) except the Soul Knife get Bonus Disciplines:

> At 1st level, you learn two additional psionic disciplines of your choice. They must be chosen from among [your Order's] disciplines.

One psionic discipline can normally be swapped out every time you level up:

> In addition, whenever you gain a level in this class, you can replace one discipline you know with a different one of your choice.

Can the Bonus Disciplines gained from a Mystic Order also be swapped out, even for replacements that aren't from the Order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, you can replace Bonus Disciplines with any other discipline.

As you note, the [Psionic Disciplines](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=3) feature says:

> In addition, whenever you gain a level in this class, you can replace one discipline you know with a different one of your choice.

When you gain a level in the mystic class, you can replace any discipline you know with any other discipline. And as you've noted, you learn the Bonus Disciplines gained from your Mystic Order, after which you know them. Thus, those disciplines can be replaced upon level up, just like any other.

---

Rules designer Jeremy Crawford confirmed this ruling (and its significance) in a [concise pair of tweets in March 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/841446695925821440):

> *When replacing disciplines known upon level-up, can you switch disciplines granted by an order with ones of another order?*
>
> **Yep.**
>
> *So in the long run, the fact that the extra disciplines must be from your order is more of a flavor thing, right?*
>
> **Yep.**

Ultimately, the requirement that the bonus disciplines must be initially chosen from [those listed for your Order](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=10) is not meant as a hard limit that restricts them forever - simply as a reason to pick additional disciplines that fit the flavor of your mystic order.